# How to resolve spring <mvc:resorces....> error without maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to print a simple hello message using an HTML file through Spring MVC.

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SampleApplication</display-name>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>html/homepage.html</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>

</web-app>
```

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config.properties"/>

    <!-- Spring will search in the bellow paths controller an services annotations-->   
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.itc" /> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/html/**" location="/html/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- More code goes here -->
</beans>
```

**RiskController.java**

```
package org.itc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller  
public class RiskController {  
    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public void helloWorld() {  
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        System.out.println(message); 
    }  
}
```

In HTML file Im just trying to print a hello message(Not through Java Controller file as of now).
Im getting the error- The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 18 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 57; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 57; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:resources'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Which spring version are you using? And add your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using Spring-3.0.1 and I dont want to use Maven as of now

Comment: That version doesn't have the `resources` tag... It was introduced in 3.0.4 . If you don't want maven then why is your question tagged with maven? I would suggest using the latest 4.3 or 4.2 version. 3.0 is old and not maintained/supported anymore.